# Android textview layout background to allow text to fit in and size automatically

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a following layout .xml. What I am trying to create is a google marker below and dialog/bubble image on top it. What I want is that the background image to scale according to text content. Below is my codes.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialogimage2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog"
            android:text="PKH 52363"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:padding="3sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.70" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/markerImage"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/basgray" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is what I have attached the image how the design looks like.
[image]

Comment: Use wrap_content rather than fixed size in Textview.

Comment: @aksacha what to wrap? I dont get you ?

Comment: just set             android:gravity="center"
    to  TextView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog background probably should be a ninepatch drawable. See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136672/discussion-on-answer-by-piotr-zawadzki-android-textview-layout-background-to-all).

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content`.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialogimage2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog"
            android:text="My text to be in"
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.08" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/markerImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/basgray" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the image view becomes to big ? Earlier I set as this android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"?

Comment: then make it 50dp

Comment: I have made it back but I need to adjust android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp" to make it below the dialog? But I notice the text is not fit in well? Do you think I should increase the text size ?

Comment: I notice when I change my text content it does not stay in centered anymore? Even though my android:gravity="center"

Comment: i think for image you have to use ninepatch drawable

Comment: How to design that image? Can I draw in normal format? I am not good in this graphic?

Comment: I have updated my question with latest layout.xml and screenshot too.